# How to get offsetTop for fixed positioned element relative to the document

Tags: javascript

I would like to find the distance between the top of the document to the element which is fixed positioned on scroll using Vanilla javascript.

The code mentioned below returns the distance relative to the window rather than with respect to the document.

JS:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('butterfly')[0].offsetTop);
```

CSS:

```
.butterfly {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.scrollY` to get the scroll distance from top of the document to the current position.